How to beautify filter path url?
currently using a filter to create seo friendly pages. URL looks like this:
website.com/shop/filter/product_cat-xxxx-and-xxx-and-xxx
I wish to show it to customer as
website.com/shop/puzzles/adventure
But I got no idea how to achieve it. Pages are dynamic (created by filter).

Please edit your question to provide more information. What filter are you referring to? How is the SEO-friendly URL generated? Do you want the same page to have two URLs, one for customers and one for SEO?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
